# Integer Overflow when Passing Arguments in C

Tags: c, parameter-passing, integer-overflow

I think I'm having an integer overflow issue and I'm not sure how to fix it.  I just started C coming from Python and JS and this is all new to me.

I put a really simple example below of what is happening.  I'm passing an argument from the `main` function to a different function to multiply by 3, but when it's passed, the number overflows.  The math works in the `main` function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

long long calc(number) {
    return number * 3;
}

int main(void)
{
    long long digits = 1111111111111;
    long long result = calc(digits);
    printf("calc result: %lld\n", result);
    
    long long mainTimes3 = digits * 3;
    printf("main result: %lld\n", mainTimes3);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the error message

> main.c:3:11: warning: type of ‘number’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]`

The `printf` is showing

```
calc result: 438711637
main result: 3333333333333
```

Comment: Change the function declaration to `long long calc(long long number)`.

Comment: As @Murenik says in his answer, in C if you don't explicitly provide a **type** for the variable (or function, etc...) everything defaults to `int`. Your `number * 3` would exceed the signed value representable as an `int`. (signed overflow -> *Undefined Behavior*)

Comment: Note that this will no longer be valid `C` code since `C23`, which removed implicit `int` parameters and implicit `int` return types.

Comment: That is a great point @WeijunZhou.  But, oh joy, behavior will dramatically change depending on whether it is `-std=c20` or `-std=c23`... `:)` (it had to happen sometime -- might as well be now -- it's a good thing, but lots of work for legacy code maintainers...)

Comment: @WeijunZhou, the code given is not valid even in *C99*.  Starting in that version, K&R-style function definitions require every parameter identifier to be declared in the declaration list.  This is explicitly specified, but it goes along with the fact that C99 removes implicit typing overall, so the type of every function parameter needs to declared explicitly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the correction. I was under the impression that it was only deprecated but not actually made invalid in C99. So it turns out `long long calc(number) long long number;{...}` is valid C99, but will be invalid in C23. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, @WeijunZhou.

Comment: C99 made implicit typing illegal.  Many compilers did not enforce C99 rules by default.  Indeed, GCC never enforced C99 by default.  It does now assume C11 by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler warning hints at the problem - since you didn't explicitly define the type of the `number` parameter, the compiler assumes it's an `int`. Therefore `number * 3` is also an `int`, and an integer overflow occurs.

To solve the issue, explicitly define it as the type you intended, `long long`:

```c
long long calc(long long number){
    /* Here ---^ */
    return number * 3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I tried ((long long) number) because I thought you needed parentheses, but I have no idea where I got that.

Answer (score 3):

> I think I'm having an integer overflow issue and I'm not sure how to fix it. I just started C coming from Python and JS and this is all new to me.

Then one of the things you need to accustom yourself to is that in C, you must explicitly specify the data type of every variable, every function parameter, and every structure or union member, and the return type of every function.  And note well that array types comprise the data type of the array elements, and pointer types comprise the data type of the object or function to which the pointer points.  Every expression in C99 and later has a data type that can be traced back, possibly in light of type conversions, to one or more explicit type declarations and / or to constants and literals whose data types are conveyed by their form.

Primordial C had provisions for default typing (to type `int`), and for backwards compatibility, this was carried forward into the first version of the C standard.  Some compilers still support that for (still) backwards compatibility, but since C99, standard C does not provide for default typing.  Compilers that support it in (otherwise) C99 or later mode are thereby implementing an extension.

Thus the problem with this function:

> ```
> long long calc(number){
>     return number*3;
> }
> ```

is that the data type of parameter `number` has not been declared.  That is what the warning is telling you.

A secondary problem is that that makes the function definition a K&R-style one, which has been disfavored for years and is removed in C23.  Although you could fix the typing issue without converting from K&R style, it would be both easier and better to convert to ANSI style by putting the desired data type in the function parameter list, like so:

```
long long calc(long long number) {
    return number * 3;
}
```

Final note: at your level of C experience, you should not consider any warning emitted by your compiler to be ignorable.  Make sure you understand and fix each one, even though the compiler may produce an executable when you haven't.

Answer (score 1):

In C, it defaults to int when you don't specify a data type for a func parameter.
-> you're getting a warning `main.c:3:11: warning: type of number defaults to int [-Wimplicit-int]`.

In C program, we should remember to specify the data type for parameters in our defined funcs.

As your example, we should define it as `long long`

```c
long long calc(long long number){}
```

Comment: No version of standard C from this millennium allows the untyped parameter.  Many compilers continue to allow it because it was valid in C90 and pre-standard C, but people learning C should not use the licence that C90 gave.

Comment: Yes, it right. The untyped parameter was removed from the C standard in C99 and untyped parameters it can lead to errors and difficult to write portable code to run on multiple platform.

Answer (score 1):

This definition:

```
long long calc(number) {
    return number * 3;
}
```

is the old Kernighan & Ritchie C language definition way of declaring parameters.   The `number` parameter, lacking a definition, defaults to `int`, enforcing the overflow.

You can solve it using the *DEPRECATED* old K&R fashion with:

```
long long calc(number)
lont long number;
{
    ...
```

or with the new ansi-c (should not say *new*, as it is very old right now):

```
long long calc(long long number)
{
    ...
```